# How to combine jdbc-helper with c3p0

Tags: jdbc, c3p0

I did not find clearly in docs a example of using [jdbc-helper](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jdbc-helper/) and c3p0.

And my question is:
to do that is simple as bellow?

```
ComboPooledDataSource datasource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
//Setting connection parameters properly... 

JdbcHelper jdbc = new JdbcHelper(datasource);
```

Did someone already combined both in real projects?

**Update**

I'm having "*timeout at awaitAvailable*" errors (due to reaching the pool limit of open connections). I have set checkout timeout to 10s.
But, as I know, jdbc-help automatic closes connection after using it.

So, maybe I'm not combining them well.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to the question you asked, but almost all JDBC-compliant drivers have a `DataSource` class that you can use.  For example, Oracle has `OracleConnectionPoolDataSource`.  Instantiating one directly usually gives you more control and avoids timeout issues like you describe.  HTH.

Comment: Brad, but if I use OracleConnectionPoolDataSource instead of ComboPooledDataSource I'd not be using c3p0 at al, right?

Comment: Correct.  You could take that completely out of the project.

Comment: It is good to know that I have this option, but changing the pool implementation will not solve my problem. TKS.

Comment: I think that (changing pool implementation will not solve my problem) because jdbc-helper will continue leaving open connections. Am I right?

Comment: Believe it or not, I doubt it.  c3p0 handles connections differently than most internal driver classes.